# When do I have to inflate the layout of my custom view?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, custom-view, layout-inflater

I made a custom view which is used in several Fragments of an viewpager.

The view is always stored as a field of the Fragment. I inflate the layout in the constructor and everything works fine flipping through the pages. Because always the next Fragment is created the view shows up without any problem. But if I go back a destroyed View of a Fragment is recreated and it gives me an error, because I still use the same custom view, which isn't inflated, because the constructor isn't called.

So, when do I have to inflate my layout of the custom view? I don't think code would clear anything up, but I can deliver if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In this function:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The reference is [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: I am talking about a normal CustomView. Not about a Menu. Are you sure you read the question correctly or answered to the right question?

Comment: If is not a menu, the inflate code on the constructor (i assume oncreate) must work.

Comment: Always a activity is destroy, go to oncreate again when you return. Is the same that if you turn the orientation, go to onDestroy and then oncreate again.  The consttructor must be called

Comment: But we aren't talking about an Activity. It's in a Fragment and it's not destroyed, only the onViewDestroy-method is called, not the onDestroy-method. Please read my question once again.

Answer (score 1):

I have a class `DynamicRowView` which contains view. You can create a class and call the this class in your main file:

```
public class DynamicRowView
{
    public View getView(int layout_id,Activity context)
    {
        View view = null;
        view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout_id, null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and write this in your main class where you want the `View`:

```
dynamic_row_view = new DynamicRowView();

View view = dynamic_row_view.getView(R.layout.row_menu_list, MenuListingPage.this);
```